# Better ways to add a "filter" method to a list of elements?

Tags: java, filter

I want to implement a filter method to a list of elements in java, so I can get rid of some elements in the list according to my filter. And, most important, I want to design the interface as simple as possible.

Here's my implementation:
I created a class named EasierList, and in the class, I added a method whose signature and implementation is like below:

```
public IEasierList<T> filter(ISelection<T> filter) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T item : mInternalList) {
        if(filter.accept(item)) {
            result.add(item);
        }
    }

    mInternalList = result;
    return new EasierList<T>(this);
}
```

As for the ISelection interface, it is quite a easy one:

```
public boolean accept(T obj);
```

So, you can tell, the users who use this class need to write some code like this to use the filter:

```
aEasierList.filter(new ISelection<T>() {
@Override
public boolean accept(T obj) {
        // some test
    return false;
}
});
```

And I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, I mean to make the interface even easier to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Two points:

First, you don't have to reinvent the wheel, you can use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which already supports [filtering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) and [transforming](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) of collections and iterables. Sure, those methods are static, but you can use them for standard `List`, `Collection` or `Iterable` interfaces.

Second, since Java doesn't yet support lambda expressions (planned for Java 8), the verbose anonymous classes are the only way how to implement a function object (if you don't want to create a full blown named class). However, you can help yourself a little by not implementing the anonymous class in-place, but by storing it in a static field:

```
private static final Predicate<String> startsWithS = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(String string) {
        return string.startsWith("S");
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
Collection<String> strings = ...
Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(strings, startsWithS);
```

**Edit:**

One more important thing should be mentioned: These `filter` and `transform` methods do not create a new collection independent on the original. What they create is a "view", which is technically a proxy object that points to the original collection and lazily applies the given `Predicate` or `Function` on its elements during iteration, querying etc.

This is sometimes convenient, but you have to remember, that in order to obtain a new collection that is independent (not deeply, of course) on the original one, you need to pass it to a constructor (or a factory) of a new collection.

```
List<String> filteredList =
    new ArrayList<>(Collections2.filter(strings, startsWithS));
```

By the way, this might be a good occasion to use static import for the `filter` method to reduce the verbosity a little.

Comment: I believe the lambda expressions are easier to use in this situation. And thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best you can do in native Java without resorting to an alternate JVM language (Groovy, Scala) that supports closures.

Commons Collections implements essentially the same pattern - check out docs for `CollectionUtils.filter` and `Predicate`.  The only downside is it doesn't support generics.

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

So if you're going that route, you may as well use something that's already written and tested.

C# also has a good solution to this pattern via LINQ and extension methods, which makes something analogous to the above `filter` method appear like it belongs to the `Collection` itself.

Comment: Frankly speaking, my version of design is inspired by LINQ, in my IEasierList interface, I added some methods like take, skip. I believe these are easier to use.

Comment: Commons Collections were great in the past, but the absence of generics is in my view fatal. I'd definitely choose Guava over them.